# Jenkins - receive build status from remotely started build

Tags: python, rest, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I got multi-thread python code that starts remotely Jenkins job
I used the common code

```
nextBuildReq=urllib.request.urlopen(serverURL+'/job/'+jobName+'/api/json')
jobStream=json.load(nextBuildReq)
nextBuild=str(jobStream['nextBuildNumber'])
jenkinsStream = urllib.request.urlopen(serverURL+'/job/'+jobName+'/buildWithParameters?token=myToken')
```

I need a way to avoid requesting the next build number and "follow" the results for job the thread started since I got simultaneous requests

I also tried using

```
status = requests.get(job_url)
```

but status doesn't contains any needed information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jenkins-cli solvs the issue

```
java -jar {self.local_cli_path} -noCertificateCheck build {self.jobName} -s -w -v
```

The return value is job ID